# fadeIn and Out effect on hover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm currently using a hover effect using jQueryUI like this:

```
$('#menu-header-menu li a').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#eaeaea'}, 500);
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#fff'}, 500);
    }
);
```

But I feel that including both jQuery and jQueryUI libraries to accomplish this isn't necessary. Is there any smart way to do this using `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` with only jQuery?

I've tried some various things but can't make it work without jQueryUI.

Thanks / Tobias

Comment: ... there's nothing in your code that involves jQuery UI. `animate` is a standard jQuery method: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ What error are you seeing, exactly?

Comment: @Victor - You need UI to animate color transitions.

Comment: @patrick : you are correct. And it's right there on the page I linked to. /shame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to perform animations with colors, you will need to use the [jQuery Color Animations Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.color.js.txt) or a bare-bones `fx` package from `jQuery UI`.

Comment: but I could perhaps fadeIn a class which has the correct color?

Comment: Color fading is not in the core jQuery library.  Only opacity fading is available without other plugins.

Comment: perhaps I could use the background color as default and lower the opacity to zero and then fadeIn opacity when hovering?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can animate to a class with this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/animate-to-class